# Chrome and Opera fail when using floats

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera

I am using floats when specifying dimensions of an element. Please see this jsfiddle [jsfiddle.net/yMTGJ](http://jsfiddle.net/yMTGJ) But both Chrome and Opera fail setting up the right widths and as a result there one pixel gap between the two divs, as you can see from see image [i.stack.imgur.com/O9ZxW.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ZxW.png) Can't Chrome and Opera handle the float properly? Why is there that one pixel gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because you're specifying the width as `466.5px`, wich is roundet up to `467px` by other browsers (firefox for example). chrome tries to render this correctly, so there's a one pixel line that shows in red/yellow combined (wich confuses the browser and looks like but isn't a gap).

to avoid this, don't use half pixels to specify dimensions (what did you think the example should look like? chrome does exactly what i would expect, but i don't know your intention to use half pixels).

take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Lupna/ where i have adjusted the width of the outer div to `932px` and the inner ones to `466px` - works perfectly on chrome.

**EDIT:**
another solution that would make all browsers display the same if you need a width of `933px` would be to built in a gap on your own that should be there: http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Qd/

Comment: Well, 933 (the parent width) / 2 (the number of the children) =  466.5 so that is why.

Comment: But I still don't understand why there is the so-called gap.

Comment: The example should look as follows: one child occupies 50% and the other one occupies 50%, given that, there should be no gap.

Comment: because there's a `1px` line that's half yellow and half red wich simply can't be displayed by the browser (maybe tis line should be orange instead of white, but you won't (and shouldn't) get a sharp edge)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy so `932px` is not a solution to me.

Comment: I understand what you mean by "half yellow and half red", but it's horrible it's not possible for Chrome and Opera to work it out the way Firefox does.

Comment: @Hitch: This is not a simple problem to solve. None of the different results between browsers are wrong, just.. different. More info: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/.

Answer (score 1):

There's your problem: `width: 466.5px;` Decimal point is not universally supported. Some info and possible solution: http://www.latentmotion.com/browsers-trim-pixel-decimals/

Answer (score 1):

As said above the problem is with the half pixel. Monitors work and pixels which is a block of light which cannot be halfed. Some browsers may try and be clever to fix this problem but you cannot obtain a consistent result across all browsers when doing this.

I would recommend you work to a 960px width and use something like http://www.960.gs

There is no way you can get this to work as it is not valid CSS.